# What's the 'curious' badge?

Tags: support, badges

Today I was awarded a new badge, the 'curious' badge.

[image]

What exactly is that?

What does

> Asked a good question **on 5 separate days**, and maintains a positive question record

mean?

The same goes for the   'Inquisitive' and  'Socratic' badges.

Comment: I'm *curious* about this badge myself.